# Kusto Query Parser C#: Get function name from columns in query

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer, kql

I got a query like the following:

```
Function
| where Column1="abc"
| where Column2="abcd123"
...
```

I tried using a ColumnSymbol parser as said in the repo's [README](https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language/blob/master/src/Kusto.Language/readme.md), but I can't seem to extract the used columns `Column1`, `Column2`..., because the repo's example makes us dive into the function bodies.

I've managed to get the columns without the function name, and the function name but with all the columns in the function body, but not the ones in the query body...

I'd like to have something like this

```json
{
   "function": "FunctionName",
   "columns": ["Column1", "Column2"]
}
```

I want to remain surface-level and query-level.

How do I do so?

TIA

**EDIT:**
Per David's request, I'm providing an example:

```
let UCName = "AD - Suspicious Domain Account Property Changed";
Function_Name
| extend cust_server = strcat (customerURI_s, ":", UCName)
| where deviceVendor == "Microsoft" and deviceProduct == "Microsoft Windows" 
...
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    public static class QueryParsingService
    {
        [FunctionName("QueryParsingService")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string query = "";

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            var cluster = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLUSTER_ENDPOINT");
            var connection = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(cluster, "DATABASE_NAME").WithAadAzCliAuthentication(false);
            var server = new ServerSymbolLoader(connection);
            var databaseNames = await server.GetDatabaseNamesAsync(cluster, true);
            var databaseSchema = await server.LoadDatabaseAsync("DATABASE_NAME", null, true);
            var globals = GlobalState.Default.WithDatabase(databaseSchema);
            var dataModelsList = new List<Object>();
            foreach (var dataModel in data)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Current rule name : " + dataModel.rule);
                query = dataModel?.query;
                string rule = dataModel.rule;
                KustoCode code = KustoCode.Parse(query, globals).Analyze();
                var dataModels = GetTablesWithColumns(code);
                var dataModelResponse = new DataModelResponse(rule, dataModels);
                dataModelsList.Add(dataModelResponse);
            }
            dataModelsList.RemoveAll(d => d.DataModels.Count() == 0);
            return new OkObjectResult(dataModelsList);
        }
```

As you can see, I am connecting to the cluster, pulling the database, tables and functions schemes and pushing into `globals`, which are used in the Parser.
While debugging, I can confirm that it's working as expected since it can link the Symbol to the Entity in the Database.

The `GetTablesWithColumns` is the following:

```
public static HashSet<ColumnSymbol> GetDatabaseTableColumns(KustoCode code)
    {
        var columns = new HashSet<ColumnSymbol>();
        GatherColumns(code.Syntax);
        return columns;

        void GatherColumns(SyntaxNode root)
        {
            SyntaxElement.WalkNodes(root,
                fnBefore: n =>
                {
                    if (n.ReferencedSymbol is ColumnSymbol c
                        && code.Globals.GetTable(c) != null)
                    {
                        columns.Add(c);
                    }
                    else if (n.GetCalledFunctionBody() is SyntaxNode body && n.ReferencedSymbol is FunctionSymbol f && !code.Globals.IsBuiltInFunction(f))
                    {
                        // Here is the issue, I can't seem to reach the object that contains the ReferencedSymbol that points to ColumnSymbol.
                    }
                },
                fnDescend: n =>
                    // skip descending into function declarations since their bodies will be examined by the code above
                    !(n is FunctionDeclaration)
                );
        }
    }
```

In my situation, I do provide a global definition of both table & function schemes, so they do have access to `Function`'s definition.
Ideally, a method like `code.Globals.GetFunction(c)` (where we'd pass the `ColumnSymbol`) would be perfect, as it creates the relationship between the Output column & Function.

Comment: In the example that you gave, there is no way for the parser to figure out that *Function* is indeed a function and not a table. There is no function body, because toy haven't provided a function definition. Please modify the example to match your actual scenario.

Comment: Just added some information in the edit section.

Comment: What about the KQL code that you are trying to parse or at least a small but representative sample of it?

Comment: Added. In my case, I don't mind the extend column, but i'd rather focus on the where columns.

Comment: Still missing the important stuff. How is the function defined? Is it an object or an ad hoc definition?

Comment: In the KQL query? `Function_Name` is an already existing function in the ADX database, defined with a `FunctionBody` and is a `TabularFunction`. The columns I want (`deviceVendor`, `deviceProduct`) are columns that are present in the `OutputColumns` array we see in the function's schema.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is actually defined in your database. You are not connected to the cluster. You're just parsing a text. There is no way to distinguish between a function and a table like that.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Please assume I'm connected to a cluster, and pulled the schema, and loaded it into the Parser thru the globals object in the C# code. I've just didn't add it for consistency's sake.

Comment: I've added the Database connection code if it helps.